IIS IP Restriction Feature settings change with powershell
I'm trying to update the deny action type under feature settings in "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" in IIS using Powershell to Abort instead of Forbidden
I've run the following command in Powershell which has made the change in the ApplicationHost.config file in configuration editor:
Set-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/security/dynamicIpSecurity" -name "denyAction" -value "AbortRequest"

However, it doesn't seem to be changing the drop down value under feature settings in IIS gui itself but the change is reflected in Configuration Editor.
Not sure if I'm missing something or I've entering the wrong command to change this or something but I've tried restarting IIS after making the change, stopping IIS, making the change, then starting IIS again and I've run the set command between the start and stop IISCommitDelay commands but nothing seems to be changing it
I'm a bit new to IIS so any insight or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

There seems to be no problem with this command. What requirements do you want to achieve in iis? Maybe you can change the method.

I'm trying to change the "Deny Action Type" drop down value to Abort in "Edit Feature Settings" in "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" in IIS. I thought the above command was how you do this but it seems to only make the change in the configuration editor and doesn't change the drop down value.
